# Print function inside constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

below is a part of my code(using a constructor). In this the printf before the scanf doesnt show up while i run the code. I get a blank screen in which i have to enter the no and then the printf results are showing. can someone help me on this? I need the "Enter no of points" to be displayed so that i can understand which entry i am making

```
Discret::Discret()
{

  rich = 0;
  solve  = 0;
  total  = 0;
  int no;
  double no;
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("==============================================================\n");
  printf("Input:\n");
  printf("Enter the number of points" );
  scanf("%d",&no);
  printf("==============================================================\n");

  /************************************
   *
   * Material
   *
   ************************************/
  double youngs, poisson;

  S  = 1000;
  P = 0.0;

  material.resize(1);
  material[0] = new Material(youngs, poisson);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` works on buffered stream. You need to flush it

```
printf("Enter the number of points" );
fflush( stdout);
//...
scanf("%d",&no);
printf("==============================================================\n");
fflush( stdout);
```

When working with C++ streams you will use

```
std::cout.flush();  // or std::cout << flush;
```

Comment: plus `printf` is pretty C, I'd rather use `std::cout`.

Comment: @Theolodis printf is C, but std::printf is more C++. And it's faster than std::cout

Comment: @user2420535 printf is still a C function it is even in the C header `cstdio`.